# CSS multiple animation with different delay

Tags: css, animation

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

```css
p {
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

is equivalent to

```js
p {
  animation: 3s infinite alternate slidein;
}
```

---

Applying multiple animation on a same element can be achieved by:

```html
<div></div>
```

```css
@keyframes animScale{
    from{
        transform: scale(0.2, 0.2);
    }
    to{
        transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
}

@keyframes animOpacity{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    animation: animScale 2000ms ease-in-out infinite,
    animOpacity 2000ms ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

---

Is there a way I can write `animation-delay` into the property `animation`, so that I can have two animations starting from different time?

Comment: Yes, just add another time after `2000ms`, the second time value in `animation` shorthand is considered as `animation-delay`

Comment: @HaoWu actually it should go after the easing (AKA timing-function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the delay *after* the easing (AKA timing-function) value.

```css
div{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  animation: animScale 2000ms ease-in-out 1000ms infinite,
             animOpacity 2000ms ease-in-out 2000ms infinite;
  /* scale will start after 1s and opacity after 2s (1s after the scale)*/
}
```

the values being:

> animation-**name**: name
> animation-**duration**: 0
> animation-**timing-function**: ease
> animation-**delay**: 0
> animation-**iteration-count**: 1
> animation-**direction**: normal
> animation-**fill-mode**: none
> animation-**play-state**: running

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation
- https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animation

Comment: there is no order to follow, it can be any order. Check the formal syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#formal_syntax. There is `||` which means *any* order. There is only some particular rules defined in the Spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-animations/#animation related to parsing of the time and animation name. Ex: https://jsfiddle.net/ozrm6xL3/1/

Comment: Yes, but how would you do this if you didn't want to use the shorthand syntax? i.e.: `animation-name: anim1; animation-name: anim2; animation-delay: 1s; animation-delay:2s;`? Does the second `animation-delay` overwrite the previous value, or does it apply the second delay declaration to the second name declaration in declaration order? It's unclear...

Comment: @TomAuger the rules of overriding are the same as in other CSS properties. A `color: red;` will be overridden by `color: blue;` - the same rule applies.